# How do I make the UIImage not an object of the file owner?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, custom-cell

I am creating a custom cell and always get the error

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key concert. read that the file owner should not be the object.

How would I change it and what would I change it to? I used this as reference [Custom UITableViewCell gives me: this class is not key value coding-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985487/custom-uitableviewcell-gives-me-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant)

[image]

Comment: You may have a bad connection in your xib. or Your view controller may have the wrong class in your xib. plz tell me the result

Comment: The file owner's class is connected to the `CustomCellConcerts`

Comment: check wether have two outlet connection or not of one object

Comment: I connected the cell to the custom class, and now I'm getting the error `error: failed to attach to process ID ...`

Comment: you can't connect the cell directly . you just can make outlet connections between objects in cell and your cell class. if you need a custom cell it is another story

Comment: What would I have to do differently for a custom cell. That is what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually received due to a type mismatch with the class defined in the .xib file. Is it possible that your file owner's class is set as `UITableViewCell` instead of `CustomCellConcerts`? If so, it can explain why it cannot find the `concert` outlet and causes the app to crash. Simply change the file owner's class to your custom class and re-attach the outlet.

Comment: The file owner's class is connected to the `CustomCellConcerts`